# Declare Double as int compile vs not compile but appears same

Tags: java

(note: Double is just an example)

When initializing a Double it needs a Double or double as value:

```
Double a = 0; //does not compile
```

unless you cast to double, or append 'd'

```
Double b = (double)0; //compiles
Double c = 0d; //compiles
```

When it becomes confusing is...
This compiles, although its value becomes 0 (int)

```
Double d = true ? 0 : 0d; //compiles, but always 0 (eclipse 'complains' on 0d calling it *Dead code*. So it knows it will return 0
```

As does this

```
Double e = false ? 0 : 0d; //compiles, always 0d
```

But these do not compile:

```
Double f = false ? 0 : 0; //cannot convert from int to Double
Double g = true ? 0 : 0; //cannot convert from int to Double
```

Why is it given an error for *f* and *g* but not for *d*

ps. Using Java8 (expect not a difference, but upgrades happen)

Comment: Yes this is very confusing. It's best to explicitly supply the desired type, instead of relying on java's magical auto conversions, which is all to complicated.

Comment: I disagree. Only when you understand something, you can use it to your advantage. But, one should describe what one is doing.

Comment: Ideally. But nobody fully understands java's [conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) :) What I mean is, even though you could write `double x=0`, which relies on auto conversion, it's better to be more explict, like `double x=0d` or `double x=(double)0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compiles because according to Java specs (at **§15.25**), if operands have different types and they're convertible to numeric types then binary numeric promotion applies (at **§5.6.2**):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

It doesn't matter if double is first or second operand, result will be a double.

Going back to your examples:

```
Double e = false ? 0 : 0d; 
Double a = true ? 0 : 0d;
```

They're all converted to double because of **numeric promotion** however this:

```
Double f = false ? 0 : 0;
```

It will fail because result of `condition ? 0 : 0` is always an integer, from **§15.25** we know that:

> If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.

And assignment is invalid. Note that this exact case is used in specs to illustrate numeric promotion applied to ternary operators at **§5.6.2-1**:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        float f = 1.0f;

        // Omitted code...

        // Here int:float is promoted to float:float:
        f = (b==0) ? i : 4.0f;
        System.out.println(1.0/f);
    }
}
```

Finally note that your *required* final type (the one ternary operator expression will be used vs) doesn't play in this *game* and this code doesn't compile:

```
int n = true ? 0 : 0d; // Cannot assign a double to an int
```

Comment: Hmmm. I might need to 'learn' the Java Specs. Luckily https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ only has 788 pages. (something to do over the weekend :p)

Comment: @Danielson perfect lecture in train and bus! Thank to include a link back to specs, I forgot that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator needs both values to be of a single type. Since you have an int and a double and there is a conversion possible from int to double without loss of precision*, they will both be converted.

Therefore if you do

```
Double d = true ? 1 : 2.0;
```

It is actually compiled as

```
Double d = true ? (double)1 : 2.0;
```

Therefore there will be no problems with the code. If both values are int, then the common type is int and no implicit conversion is made.

* with long and double or int and float there might not be possibility to convert without loss of precision since there aren't enough bits in the mantissa to represent all integer values exactly

Comment: Makes sense... As long as it is an upcast to the returned type